# How to keep track of status with multiprocessing and pool.map?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm setting up a multiprocessing module for the first time, and basically, I am planning to do something along the lines of

```
from multiprocessing import pool
pool = Pool(processes=102)
results = pool.map(whateverFunction, myIterable)
print 1
```

As I understand it, `1` will be printed as soon as *all* the processes have come back and results is complete. I would like to have some status update on these. What is the best way of implementing that?

I'm kind of hesitant of making `whateverFunction()` print. Especially if there's around 200 values, I'm going to have something like 'process done' printed 200 times, which is not very useful.

I expect output like

```
10% of myIterable done
20% of myIterable done
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pool.map` blocks until all the concurrent function calls have completed.
`pool.apply_async` does not block. Moreover, you could use its `callback` parameter
to report on progress. The callback function, `log_result`, is called once each time `foo` completes. It is passed the value returned by `foo`.

```
from __future__ import division
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def foo(x):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return x

def log_result(retval):
    results.append(retval)
    if len(results) % (len(data)//10) == 0:
        print('{:.0%} done'.format(len(results)/len(data)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    results = []
    data = range(200)
    for item in data:
        pool.apply_async(foo, args=[item], callback=log_result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(results)
```

yields

```
10% done
20% done
30% done
40% done
50% done
60% done
70% done
80% done
90% done
100% done
[0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 197, 198, 199]
```

---

The `log_result` function above modifies the global variable `results` and
accesses the global variable `data`.  You can not pass these variables to
`log_result` because the callback function specified in `pool.apply_async` is
always called with exactly one argument, the return value of `foo`.

You can, however, make a closure, which at least makes clear what variables
`log_result` depends on:

```
from __future__ import division
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def foo(x):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return x

def make_log_result(results, len_data):
    def log_result(retval):
        results.append(retval)
        if len(results) % (len_data//10) == 0:
            print('{:.0%} done'.format(len(results)/len_data))
    return log_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool()
    results = []
    data = range(200)
    for item in data:
        pool.apply_async(foo, args=[item], callback=make_log_result(results, len(data)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(results)
```

Comment: Great. I see that you're using variables outside the function scope inside `log_result()`. Can I do something along the lines of `callback=lambda x: log_result(x, results)` to prevent that?

Comment: Yes, you could, but the `lambda` function would also be accessing a variable outside its scope. Since the callback function *must* accept one and only one argument, the return value of `foo`, there is no way to supply `results` (and `data`) as local variables to the callback function. You can, however, use a closure to make `results` and `len_data` variables in the parent function's nonlocal scope instead of globals. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.

Comment: Wow, that's a really smart construct.